# Apuntar subdominio en Apache

Tags: apache, red-hat

Un cliente apunto un subdominio a mi servidor, desde apache configure para tomar ese subdominio y apuntarlo a la carpeta deseada, pero no logro conservar la url del dominio, en cambio me muestra la ip de mi servidor. Que configuración me hace falta?

ssl.conf

```
Listen 443
NameVirtualHost *:443
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
# SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/random  512
# SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/random  512
# SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 512
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1


<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName subdominio2
 DocumentRoot carpeta subdominio2
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile camino a certificado.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile camino a key.key
 # SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName subdominio1
 DocumentRoot carpeta subdominio1
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile camino a certificado.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile camino a key.key
# SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

El subdominio1 funciona correctamente el subdominio2 es el problema. y creo que tengo la misma configuracion.

Comment: Agrega las configuraciones que tienes, caso contrario, dudo que podamos ayudarte con el enunciado solamente. Show me the code!

Comment: esos virtualhost no van alli, para eso hay una carpeta especial en /etx/apache2/site-enabled/

Comment: no tengo la carpeta apache2, tengo la carpeta httpd

Comment: @JackNavaRow deberia cambiar la instalación?

Comment: busca tu carpeta site-enabled en el servidor

Comment: @JackNavaRow locate site-enabled no me devuelve ningun resultado

Comment: busca en `/etc/apache2/`

Comment: @JackNavaRow como dije antes no tengo la carpeta "apache2"